# Parameter Array String Jframe

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

Hi i am trying to print in a Jdialog the values of a selected row from the main frame .
i m trying this ,but when i call the method("m.SetRecoger) in the main frame it´s showing this error :

"method SetRecoger in class Modificar cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

the complete code :

the main frame where i have the jtable:
public class DniFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form DniFrame
 */
public DniFrame() {

    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Nif", "Nom", "Cognoms", "Telefon"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

    jButton1.setText("Actualizar Datos");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 593, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 379, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jMenu1.setText("Aplicació");

    jMenuItem1.setText("Sortir");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Base de Dades");
    jMenu2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenu2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenuItem2.setText("Afegir");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuItem4.setText("Modificar");
    jMenuItem4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem4);

    jMenuItem3.setText("Eliminar");
    jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    dispose();


}                                          

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    new afegir(this, true).setVisible(true);


}                                          

private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
modify(); 
Modificar m=new Modificar(this, true);
m.SetRecoger();
new Modificar(this, true).setVisible(true);


}                                          

private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable2.getModel();
    int i = jTable2.getSelectedRow();

    if (i == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes selecioonar una fila");

    } else {

        int ax = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Estás seguro de que quieres eliminar este registro?");
        if (ax == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has seleccionado SI.");

           String dni = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0);
           modelo.removeRow(jTable2.getSelectedRow());

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try (Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.128/mibase", "asis", "titanic24")) {
                Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
                comando.executeUpdate("delete  from dades_pers where nif = '" + dni + "'");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro borrado");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido eliminar el registro");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DniFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   






        } else if (ax == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has seleccionado NO.");
        }



    }


}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.128/mibase", "asis", "titanic24");
        Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = comando.executeQuery("select * from dades_pers");
        ResultSetMetaData rsMD = result.getMetaData();
        int numcolumnas = rsMD.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.jTable2.setModel(modelo);

        for (int x = 1; x <= numcolumnas; x++) {
            modelo.addColumn(rsMD.getColumnLabel(x));

        }

        while (result.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[numcolumnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < numcolumnas; i++) {
                fila[i] = result.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(fila);

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
    }
```

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

```
private void jMenu2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

    añadirTabla();


}                                 

public void añadirTabla() {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.128/mibase", "asis", "titanic24");
        Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = comando.executeQuery("select * from dades_pers");
        ResultSetMetaData rsMD = result.getMetaData();
        int numcolumnas = rsMD.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.jTable2.setModel(modelo);

        for (int x = 1; x <= numcolumnas; x++) {
            modelo.addColumn(rsMD.getColumnLabel(x));

        }

        while (result.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[numcolumnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < numcolumnas; i++) {
                fila[i] = result.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(fila);

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
    }

}

public String [] modify() {

    String[] registros = new String[4];
    int i = jTable2.getSelectedRow();

    if (i == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes selecioonar una fila");
        new Modificar(this, true).setVisible(false);
    } else {

        registros[0] = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        registros[1] = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        registros[2] = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        registros[3] = (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();   
    }
    return registros;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DniFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DniFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DniFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DniFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DniFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

//the jdialog (the second frame);

public class Modificar extends javax.swing.JDialog {

```
private DniFrame p;

/**
 * Creates new form Modificar
 */
public Modificar(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
   super(parent, modal);   
   this.p= (DniFrame)parent;
    initComponents();
}


public void SetRecoger(String[] v) {
    String nif = v[0];
    String nom = v[1];
    String cognom =v[2];
    String tel = v[3];

String []datos ={nif,nom,cognom,tel};

    jTextField5.setText(nif);
    jTextField6.setText(nom);
    jTextField7.setText(cognom);
    jTextField8.setText(tel);


}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel5.setText("Nom");

    jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel6.setText("NIF");

    jLabel7.setText("Cognoms");

    jLabel8.setText("Telefon");

    jButton2.setText("Desar les dades");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Tancar");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Estat"));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 232, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(17, 17, 17)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


}                                           

private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

private void jTextField7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


}                                           

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(afegir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.128/mibase", "asis", "titanic24");

        Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();

        String nif    = jTextField5.getText();
        String nom    = jTextField6.getText();
        String cognom = jTextField7.getText();
        String tel    = jTextField8.getText();


        comando.executeUpdate("UPDATE dades_pers SET nom= '" + nom + "',cognoms='" + cognom + "',telefon= '" + tel + "' where nif= '" + nif + "'");
        conexion.close();
        jLabel1.setText("Datos Modificados  correctamente");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al modificar los datos" + e);

    }


}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    dispose();
}
```

//

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modificar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modificar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modificar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Modificar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Modificar dialog = new Modificar(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
```

Thanks!!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: BTW - Nobody in their right mind is going to trawl through 655 lines of code (which is too long to use standard code formatting with) looking for an error.  Narrow it down!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Must be in my left mind :P But I agree with you... it just happened to jump out at me when scrolling

Comment: @JavaDevil *"Must be in my left mind :P"*  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method `SetRecoger` in your `DniFrame` without passing any arguments to the method.

The method as you have defined it in your `Modificar` dialog requires a String array as an argument.

```
public void SetRecoger(String[] v) {....}
```

Since your `modify()` method returns a String array, Try this:

```
String[] mod = modify(); 
Modificar m = new Modificar(this, true);
m.SetRecoger(mod);
new Modificar(this, true).setVisible(true);
```